# QSettings: Is it possible to disable groups?

Tags: c++, qt, ini, qsettings

I am using QSettings to write an .ini file which will act as my applications configuration file. There is only one problem:

QSettings adds a group name [General] to the top of the file.

I set up the file this way:

```
QSettings settings(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + fileName, QSettings::IniFormat);
```

and write to it like so:

```
settings.setValue("some_setting", theNumber);
```

However, the program I am ultimately feeding this data to cannot deal with the [General] tag. While it is certainly an option for me to manually delete [General] from the file, I wonder if it is possible to make QSettings stop doing this.

I suspect the behavior is due to specifying `QSettings::IniFormat`. However, I do not see any other options that would tell it to stop specifying groups.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You should probably rethink using `QApplication::applicationDirPath()` as the storage location.
This is the directory the program's executable is located in and thus often not a user writable locations, e.g. software installed by an admin in a system wide location

Comment: This is from projects long past, but in my use case it was always installed to a user write able place (this was a hobbyist end user app) - but good catch

Answer (score 4):

The .ini file format is a de-facto standard based on Microsoft's implementation from Windows. It requires the presence of sections.

Whatever application you feed the file to, doesn't really implement an `.ini` file format, but something else.

Most likely you shouldn't be using `QSettings` at all, but implement the functionality manually. This shouldn't be a problem, since you only do it to "feed" the data to some other piece of software. You don't need to read it back. You can store your settings in regular `QSettings`, and then export them to a text file for that application's perusal.

Answer (score 3):

It's time to write your own QSettings file format.

"file format" is a pair of two metods with signatures:

```
bool readXmlFile(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map);
bool writeXmlFile(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map);
```

one should fill `map` from `device`, second should dump `map` to `device`. You can use there anything you want -- xml, plain text files without `[general]` group etc.

After it, you should register your new shiny format with `QSettings::registerFormat` function.

Here is documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsettings.html#registerFormat

good luck.